# Variadic constructor fails to initialise an std::array

Tags: c++, variadic-templates

Here is a snippet from my code:

```cpp
template <typename Type, unsigned int NumberOfRows, unsigned int NumberOfColumns>
class HexMatrix
{
    private:
    
        std::array<Type, NumberOfRows*NumberOfColumns>    values;
        // ...
    
    public:
        
        template <typename... OtherType>
        HexMatrix(OtherType...);
        // ...
};

template <typename Type, unsigned int NumberOfRows, unsigned int NumberOfColumns>
template <typename... OtherType>
HexMatrix<Type, NumberOfRows, NumberOfColumns>::HexMatrix(OtherType... args) : values({ args... })
{
    static_assert(NumberOfRows != 0u);
    static_assert(NumberOfColumns != 0u);
}
```

Until recently, I was able to use this code as is, and initialise the `std::array` with an `std::vector` using the constructor above. Then my PC got formatted. Now this doesn't compile anymore, even though I was using and am still using `-std=c++2a`. Here is the compilation report:

```
In file included from foo.cpp:3:
LinearAlgebra.hpp: In instantiation of ‘HexMatrix< <template-parameter-1-1>, <anonymous>, <anonymous> >::HexMatrix(OtherType ...) [with OtherType = {std::vector<long double, std::allocator<long double> >}; Type = long double; unsigned int NumberOfRows = 6; unsigned int NumberOfColumns = 6]’:
LinearAlgebra.hpp:230:9:   required from ‘static HexMatrix<Type, NumberOfRows, NumberOfColumns> HexMatrix< <template-parameter-1-1>, <anonymous>, <anonymous> >::Make(OtherType ...) [with OtherType = {std::vector<long double, std::allocator<long double> >}; Type = long double; unsigned int NumberOfRows = 6; unsigned int NumberOfColumns = 6]’
foo.cpp:93:80:   required from here
LinearAlgebra.hpp:299:98: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::array<long double, 36>::array(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)’
  299 | HexMatrix<Type, NumberOfRows, NumberOfColumns>::HexMatrix(OtherType... args) : values({ args... })
      |                                                                                                  ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/9/tuple:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/bits/hashtable_policy.h:34,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/bits/hashtable.h:35,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/unordered_map:46,
                 from Using.hpp:5,
                 from LinearAlgebra.hpp:4,
                 from foo.cpp:3:
/usr/include/c++/9/array:94:12: note: candidate: ‘std::array<long double, 36>::array()’
   94 |     struct array
      |            ^~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/array:94:12: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 1 provided
/usr/include/c++/9/array:94:12: note: candidate: ‘constexpr std::array<long double, 36>::array(const std::array<long double, 36>&)’
/usr/include/c++/9/array:94:12: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘<brace-enclosed initializer list>’ to ‘const std::array<long double, 36>&’
/usr/include/c++/9/array:94:12: note: candidate: ‘constexpr std::array<long double, 36>::array(std::array<long double, 36>&&)’
/usr/include/c++/9/array:94:12: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘<brace-enclosed initializer list>’ to ‘std::array<long double, 36>&&’
make: *** [Makefile:16: foo.o] Error 1
```

What's wrong? I tried to remove the parenthesis, and/or add another pair of brackets around `args...` but that didn't change anything. Please help?

Reproductible example:

```cpp
int main(void)
{
    const std::vector<long double> foo = { 1.L, 2.L, -6.L, 0.L };
    HexMatrix<long double, 2u, 2u> givenMatrix(foo);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question with an [mre] or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)](http://sscce.org)

Comment: @Pippin can you post `HexMatrix` initialisation from foo.cpp...

Comment: With some compilers (in c++11 only) you need `{{args...}}` (see more https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array in the example)

Comment: Thank you @NathanOliver and @mani. I should add that compilation is done using `-std=c++2a`, thank you @Botond

Comment: What do you think the `typename... OtherType` will be? It will be `vector<...>` so the type of `args...` will be `vector<...>`, and `array` has no constructor taking a `vector` in `{}`-s A solution could be to change the constructor to `HexMatrix(const array<...>&)` and use an array to initialire

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass a vector in the constructor, add a new constructor to HexMatrix:

```
#include <vector>
#include <array>
#include <algorithm>

template <typename Type, unsigned int NumberOfRows, unsigned int NumberOfColumns>
class HexMatrix
{
    private:
    
        std::array<Type, NumberOfRows*NumberOfColumns>    values;
        // ...
    
    public:
        
        template <typename... OtherType>
        HexMatrix(OtherType...);
        HexMatrix(const std::vector<Type>&);
        // ...
};

template <typename Type, unsigned int NumberOfRows, unsigned int NumberOfColumns>
template <typename... OtherType>
HexMatrix<Type, NumberOfRows, NumberOfColumns>::HexMatrix(OtherType... args) : values({ args... })
{
    static_assert(NumberOfRows != 0u);
    static_assert(NumberOfColumns != 0u);
}

template <typename Type, unsigned int NumberOfRows, unsigned int NumberOfColumns>
HexMatrix<Type, NumberOfRows, NumberOfColumns>::HexMatrix(const std::vector<Type>& vec)
{
    static_assert(NumberOfRows != 0u);
    static_assert(NumberOfColumns != 0u);
    std::copy_n(vec.begin(), NumberOfRows*NumberOfColumns, values.begin());
}

int main(void)
{
    const std::vector<long double> foo = { 1.L, 2.L, -6.L, 0.L };
    HexMatrix<long double, 2u, 2u> givenMatrix(foo);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that's what I'll do then. I'm still puzzled though, because compilation used to be 100% fine.